# How to get payload on Safari Push Notifications

Tags: safari, apple-push-notifications, safari-push-notifications

I want implement **Safari Push Notifications** In the documentation , there is a **Handling permissions for website push notifications** section for getting APNs token

But there is no way to get the notification , I need to get notification payload as it contains custom data, How can I get remote notification payload? is there any listener like `onMessage`?